# Overflow:Visible outside the container

Tags: html, css

I have a fixed width div with paragraph inside.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/HrasZ/1/

The paragraph is styled with the following css:

```
p {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: grey;
    color: white;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;        
}
```

I would like to add new css class p:hover, and show all the hidden text when hovered.

```
p:hover {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: visible;
    background: grey;
    color: white;        
}
```

But it seems that only the text is using overflow: visible, but not the background color.
Is there any way to achieve this?

NOTE: I can't change the div with.

Comment: To have the `background:darkred` you need to increase the width of div... You can use `z-index`, if you have any element right next to the div

Comment: But in my case it will brake the rest of the design, because there are other elements inside the div. Also i would like to get the grey background expanded not the darkred

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Paragraphs are block elements - they take up the width of their containers, not their content. So you could try something like this

```
p:hover {
    display:inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: visible;
    background: grey;
    color: white;        
}
```

Comment: Actually - its exactly what i was trying to achieve!